# Get datetime for USA from local time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can able to get time of local sql server by `GetDate()` function. Sql server machine is in india.

Now I want to get the current datetime of USA on same sql server what can I do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `SYSDATETIMEOFFSET` call (instead of just `GETDATE()`) to get your local time with the timezone information:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
```

and then you can use the `SWITCHOFFSET` function to define a new timezone you're interested in - based on UTC time. So the East Coast of the USA would be UTC -5 hours

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-05:00') AS 'US East Coast'
```

while the West Coast is UTC -8 hours:

```
SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), '-08:00') AS 'US West Coast'
```

Comment: In my database I have gmt time in sql server there anything so that i get gmt time

Comment: @pranay rana: GMT (or UTC) time = time with timezone = +00:00 - you should be able to use SWITCHOFFSET on that, too

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
dateadd(hh,differense_between_India_and_USA,getdate())
```

Time zones of the USA:

Pacific Standard Time (GMT -8)

Mountain Standard Time (GMT -7)

Central Standard Time (GMT -6)

Eastern Standard Time (GMT -5)

Alaska Standard time (GMT -9)

Hawaii Standard Time and Aleutian Standard Time (GMT -10)

Answer (score 1):

You will get GMT from UTC time (Coordinated Universal Time)

```
SELECT SYSUTCDATETIME()
```